# To check whether the following linear subspace is dense or not?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

If we have $T: X \to Y$ be a linear transformation where both $X$ and $Y$ are Hilbert spaces. Then if we consider the set $V = R(T)+R(T)^{\bot }$ where $R(T)$ is not closed subspace. Then is the linear subspace $V$ is dense in $Y$ or not? Under what condition it is dense? $R(T)$ is range of $T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $Y=\overline{R(T)}+R(T)^\perp$, and $R(T)$ is dense in $\overline{R(T)}$.  So given $y\in Y$, we can write $y=x_1+x_2$, where $x_1\in\overline{R(T)}, x_2\in R(T)^\perp$.  Given $\varepsilon>0$, there is some $x_1'\in R(T)$ with $\|x_1-x_1'\|<\varepsilon$.  Put $y'=x_1'+x_2$.  Then $y\in V$ and we have 
$$ \|y-y'\|=\|x_1-x_1'\|<\varepsilon, $$
and therefore $V$ is dense in $Y$.

In fact, the same proof can be used to show the following more general fact:

> If $V$ is a subspace of a Hilbert space $H$, then $V+V^\perp$ is dense in $H$.

Or, even more generally,

> If $V$ is a subspace of a Banach space $X$ whose closure is complemented in $X$  (by the subspace $W$), then $V+W$ is dense in $X$.